# Syntax to specify latest pre-release in nuget 3.2rc

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to configure my project.json file to always download the latest pre-release version of the Roslyn Nightly pacakages.

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common": "1.1.0-beta"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": { }
  }
}
```

This gets me the following version:

WARNING: Dependency specified was Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (≥ 1.1.0-beta) but ended up with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 1.1.0-beta1-20150812-01.

This is not the newest, which is advertised as:

v1.1.0-beta1-20150906-01

Any suggestions on the correct syntax in the project.json to always get the latest even if it's pre-release? Or is this a bug.

(Source for Roslyn nightly is: https://www.myget.org/gallery/roslyn-nightly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common": "1.1.0-beta1-*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": { }
  }
}
```